# Issue to get json value

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I am parsing Json in my iOS project.I am getting the following dictionary.

```
 {
   RN =     {
   status = Fails;
   };
 }
```

now I want to get key status. How i get it from dictionary.Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code you have so far.

Comment: You can retrieve it as `NSString *status = dictionary[@"RN"][@"status"];` where `dictionary` is the `NSDictionary` that you've logged in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *tmpDict = [yourDict objectForKey:@"RN"];
NSString *status = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
NSError * jsonParsingError;

NSDictionary *yourJSONDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError] //responseData is the JSON string.

NSString *status = [[yourJSONDict objectForKey:@"RN"] objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this status with a single line code

```
NSString *status = [[dict objectForKey:@"RN"] objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this..

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

NSString *status = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"RN"] objectForKey:@"status"];